# How to link with binary using mingw32 in wine

Tags: c++, binary, linker, mingw32, wine

I have made this minimal project to reproduce my link problem using mingw32 in wine32:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project("tst" VERSION 1.1.0)

add_executable("tst" "main.cpp")

add_library("resource" "text.o")
set_target_properties("resource" PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "text.o"
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY "text"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/text" "text"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_LINKER} -r -b binary "text" -o "text.o"
)
set_source_files_properties("text" PROPERTIES GENERATED true EXTERNAL_OBJECT true)

target_link_libraries("tst" "resource")
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern char _binary_text_start[];
extern char _binary_text_end[];

int main()
{
    std::string text{ _binary_text_start, _binary_text_end };
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}
```

text

```
Hello, World!
```

This project builds and runs using mingw-w64 on Linux; however, when I try to build the project in wine32, I got this output:

```
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -SZ:\var\cache\deploy\cpp -BZ:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows\CMakeFiles Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\resource.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/resource.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
[ 25%] Generating text.o
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E copy Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/text text
Z:\mingw32\bin\ld.exe -r -b binary text -o text.o
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows\CMakeFiles\resource.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\resource.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/resource.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libresource.a
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -P CMakeFiles\resource.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\resource.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
Z:\mingw32\bin\ar.exe qc libresource.a text.o
Z:\mingw32\bin\ranlib.exe libresource.a
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
[ 50%] Built target resource
mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\tst.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/tst.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\build\windows\CMakeFiles\tst.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\tst.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/tst.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tst.dir/main.cpp.obj
Z:\mingw32\bin\g++.exe   -O3 -DNDEBUG -o CMakeFiles\tst.dir\main.cpp.obj -c Z:\var\cache\deploy\cpp\main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable tst.exe
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\tst.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
Z:\cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake.exe -E rm -f CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a
Z:\mingw32\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\tst.dir\objects1.rsp
Z:\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o tst.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libtst.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\tst.dir\linklibs.rsp
z:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x43): undefined reference to `_binary_text_end'
z:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x48): undefined reference to `_binary_text_start'
z:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x68): undefined reference to `_binary_text_start'
z:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\tst.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16f): undefined reference to `_binary_text_start'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [tst.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tst.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `Z:/var/cache/deploy/cpp/build/windows'
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

nm libresource.a

```
text.o:
0000000d D _binary_text_end
0000000d A _binary_text_size
00000000 D _binary_text_start
```

objdump -f libresource.a

```
In archive libresource.a:

text.o:     file format pe-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000038:
HAS_DEBUG, HAS_SYMS, HAS_LOCALS
start address 0x00000000
```

cmake: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.19.1/cmake-3.19.1-win32-x86.zip

mingw: https://pilotfiber.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/ray_linn/GCC-10.x-with-ada/mingw32-10.2.0-crt-8.0.0-with-ada.7z

mingw-make: https://phoenixnap.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/MinGW/Extension/make/mingw32-make-3.80-3/mingw32-make-3.80.0-3.tar.gz